# In FAR manager, How to open Powershell in current path?

Tags: far

In FAR manager, I can open seperate command window at the current location by just typing start. For example, Active Panel in FAR is in c:\Projects and I type "start" it opens a new console window with path c:\projects. I want to open PowerShell with current path, For instance I type PS, it opens powershell window with location set to c:\projects.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is with this command

```
start powershell.exe -noexit -command "set-location '%cd%'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
powershell -noprofile
```

which has the side effect of not loading your profile, but since your profile contains code that sets a specific path ...

Answer (score -3):

type dot '.' and press shift+Enter.